# Pandas filtering not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new df as a subset of an existing df using:

```
filtered_df = df[((df.col == "Developing") | (df.col == "Ineffective") & (df.col_16 == "Developing") | (df.col_16== "Ineffective"))]
```

But this just returns the existing df, without any filtering applied.

I've also tried:

```
filtered_df = df[((df.col.astype(str) == "Developing") | (df.col.astype(str) == "Ineffective") & (df.col_16.astype(str) == "Developing") | (df.col_16.astype(str) == "Ineffective"))]
```

I've additionally tried switching out the `|` and `&` for `or` and `and` respectively, but that generates an error basically telling me to use the `|` or `&`.

which returns the same results

My data generally looks like this:

```
ID    loc  col         col_16      col_17    col_18
4568  12P  Effective   Ineffective Effective Developing
8521  02F  Ineffective Developing  Effective Highly Effective
```

Desired output is a filtered version of the df where only the conditions I've specified are met (col and col_16 both = "Developing" or "Ineffective").  With the example data, only the 2nd row would be returned.

Comment: What do you want the ouput ot be ? Are you sure you are trying to match the string with only column `col` ?

Comment: What is `FY151617`?

Comment: @Bharath : sorry, typos - corrected now

Comment: @Goyo: sorry, typos - corrected now

Comment: Using another pairs of brackets might get ur results.

Comment: @Bharath just tried - got `
ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 8107.`

Comment: Not outside but to differentiate two |&#39;s. For First two conditions one pair of brackets and the same for second.  Hope you got my point

Comment: @Bharath With that I get an Invalid Syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a set of parenthesis which keep the or statement grouping together:

Try this:

```
filtered_df = df[(((df['col'] == "Developing") | (df['col'] == "Ineffective")) & ((df['col_16'] == "Developing") | (df['col_16'] == "Ineffective")))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `loc` to slice the data. Supposing your original data set is as you have listed it and is stored as `df`, begin by creating a list containing the words you want to filter on.

```
content_to_filter_by = ['Developing','Ineffective']

new_df = df.loc[(df['col'].isin(content_to_filter_by))&(df['col_16'].isin(content_to_filter_by)),:].copy()
```

Documentation on using `loc` and other DataFrame slicers located [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).